# Are FutureProvider new evaluations reported to its dependants?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

Beckground: I noticed that in my app StreamProvider emits cause dependant FutureProvider to reevaluate its value, but providers dependent on this provider does not. I use Rivderpod 2.

I have a chain of dependent providers:

`FutureProvider1 -> FutureProvider2 -> StreamProvider`

So FutureProvider2 is a dependency for FutureProvider1 and StreamProvider is a dependency for FutureProvider2.

Logs show that whenever StreamProvider emits a new value, FutureProvider2 is reevaluated, but its new value is NOT used to reevaluate FutureProvider1. These providers are chained by `ref.watch()`. My goal is to make this relation fully reactive and declarative.

How to make both providers reevaluate its value whenever StreamProvider emits a new value? Should I use the new AsyncNotifierProvider for that?

Comment: `ref.watch` should update the providers, yes.

Comment: Can you share your provider code?